# Back2back addition with Jacobian Coordinate

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

I implemented below algorithm in hardware and it works fine with first point addition.

[image]

However, when I continue to perform back-to-back addition, I got the wrong result.
The part that I'm not sure here is,

1. The original calculated X3 and Y3 are still in Jacobian coordinate and I do not want to convert them back to affine coordinate due to expensive cost for doing multiplicative inverse for Z-1.
2. But I'm not sure how should I carry forward the calculated X3 and Y3 I got in 1st addition into the next addition without performing affine coordinate conversion?
3. I'm ignoring the calculated Z3 as no conversion is needed in intermediate (I assume). But I am not sure is this something that important to be carried forward to next addition?

Comment: It appear like that formula I apply won't work for back-to-back addition without converting back affine coordinate because the Z3 is not 1. Appreciate if someone can help to enlighten me?